# how would i make a link show text

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a very simple page I want to be able to show text from a link.

Here is my webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Encyclopedia</title>
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is our Encyclopedia about animals</h1>
  <p>Hello this is our Animal encyclopedia so far were still working hard to make it equal to other websites we do have a very small selection of animals you can learn about right now. It's really vauge but if you click sign up you can get updates straight
    to your email for when we have a more updated selection
  </p>
  <nav id=n av1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ImageGallery.html">Image gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="SignUp.html">SignUp</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id=n av3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="encyclopedia.html">Marine life</a></li>
      <li><a href="encyclopedia.html">Mammals</a></li>
      <li><a href="encyclopedia.html">Birds</a></li>
      <li><a href="encyclopedia.html">Reptiles</a></li>
      <li><a href="encyclopedia.html">Amphibians</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the links about animals to show text I know right now I got it set up to go to the page its already on. But how would I go about doing it so that when I click the link text about the topic appears on the page?

Comment: There's a few different ways you could do it. You could write in the info on your current page, and use js to show and hide the different elements depending on which link is clicked. Or you could create different html pages for each link and use js to asynchronously load them from the server.

Comment: @Marc-André I've accepted your edit because of the grammar fixes, but I don't understand why you removed the snippet: code snippets are useful tools that it's good to use when possible ;) I've already edited the question to insert it back

Comment: @FedericoGrandi Thanks for the edit! I was wondering also as I didn't see the snippet upon edit, but I think it was the merge of the edits, whereas it was edited before my edit, so my edit removed the snippet... It's not the first time happening, I'll try to make sure there isn't the pop-up at the top before saving next times. But thanks for fixing it!

Comment: @Marc-André No problem 

Answer (score 0):

**Lots of ways to do it but here's a simple way
You'll need a DIV to fill with text**

```
<div id="uniquename3" style="display:none; position:absolute; border-style: solid; background-color: white; padding: 5px;width:120px;">Content goes here.</div>
```

**On the Href's you'll need something like this.**

```
<a onmouseover="document.getElementById('uniquename3').innerHTML = 'Mammels\,some interesting info about mammels\, more interesting info about mammels';ShowContent('uniquename3'); return true;" onmouseout="HideContent('uniquename3'); return true;" href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename3')">Mammels</a>


// http://bontragerconnection.com/ and http://willmaster.com/
// Version: July 28, 2007
var cX = 0; var cY = 0; var rX = 0; var rY = 0;
function UpdateCursorPosition(e){ cX = e.pageX; cY = e.pageY;}
function UpdateCursorPositionDocAll(e){ cX = event.clientX; cY = event.clientY;}
if(document.all) { document.onmousemove = UpdateCursorPositionDocAll; }
else { document.onmousemove = UpdateCursorPosition; }
function AssignPosition(d) {
if(self.pageYOffset) {
rX = self.pageXOffset;
rY = self.pageYOffset;
}
else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
rX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
rY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
else if(document.body) {
rX = document.body.scrollLeft;
rY = document.body.scrollTop;
}
if(document.all) {
cX += rX;
cY += rY;
}
d.style.left = (cX+10) + "px";
d.style.top = (cY+10) + "px";
}
function HideContent(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
var dd = document.getElementById(d);
AssignPosition(dd);
dd.style.display = "block";
}
function ReverseContentDisplay(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
var dd = document.getElementById(d);
AssignPosition(dd);
if(dd.style.display == "none") { dd.style.display = "block"; }
else { dd.style.display = "none"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using js to show and hide elements based on which link is clicked.

```js
const app = {
  init: function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach(link => {
      link.addEventListener("click", app.nav);
    });
  },
  nav: function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let currentPage = ev.target.getAttribute("data-target");
    let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content')
    for(i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      if(content[i].classList.contains('showing')) {
        content[i].classList.remove("showing");
      }
    }
    document.getElementById(currentPage).classList.add("showing");
  }
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", app.init);
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
.showing {
  display: block;
}
#marine-life {
  background: green;
}
#mammals {
  background: blue;
}
#birds {
  background: yellow;
}
#reptiles {
  background: purple;
}
#amphibians {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>This is our Encyclopedia about animals</h1>
  <p>Hello this is our Animal encyclopedia so far were still working hard to make it equal to other websites we do have a very small selection of animals you can learn about right now. It's really vauge but if you click sign up you can get updates straight
    to your email for when we have a more updated selection
  </p>
  <nav id=n av1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ImageGallery.html">Image gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="SignUp.html">SignUp</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav id=n av3>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="link" data-target="marine-life" href="#">Marine life</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" data-target="mammals" href="#">Mammals</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" data-target="birds" href="#">Birds</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" data-target="reptiles" href="#">Reptiles</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" data-target="amphibians" href="#">Amphibians</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="contentWrap">
    <div id="marine-life" class="content">
      <h1>Marine Life</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis pellentesque libero. Praesent hendrerit justo hendrerit lacus rutrum, sit amet cursus arcu molestie. Duis libero ipsum, blandit at nisl vitae, convallis lobortis nulla. In pulvinar tempor justo, ut lacinia ligula vestibulum quis. Quisque elementum urna nisl, eget laoreet dolor pulvinar sit amet. Etiam in lacus feugiat, imperdiet nunc et, consectetur dui. Quisque tempor nisl dui, ac vulputate erat dictum sit amet. Quisque et orci ut eros imperdiet commodo et eget diam. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse volutpat, ligula id eleifend dignissim, leo urna iaculis massa, eu eleifend nisi urna ut tortor. Vestibulum.</p>
    </div>    
    <div id="mammals" class="content">
      <h1>Mammals</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis pellentesque libero. Praesent hendrerit justo hendrerit lacus rutrum, sit amet cursus arcu molestie. Duis libero ipsum, blandit at nisl vitae, convallis lobortis nulla. In pulvinar tempor justo, ut lacinia ligula vestibulum quis. Quisque elementum urna nisl, eget laoreet dolor pulvinar sit amet. Etiam in lacus feugiat, imperdiet nunc et, consectetur dui. Quisque tempor nisl dui, ac vulputate erat dictum sit amet. Quisque et orci ut eros imperdiet commodo et eget diam. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse volutpat, ligula id eleifend dignissim, leo urna iaculis massa, eu eleifend nisi urna ut tortor. Vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="birds"class="content">
      <h1>Birds</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis pellentesque libero. Praesent hendrerit justo hendrerit lacus rutrum, sit amet cursus arcu molestie. Duis libero ipsum, blandit at nisl vitae, convallis lobortis nulla. In pulvinar tempor justo, ut lacinia ligula vestibulum quis. Quisque elementum urna nisl, eget laoreet dolor pulvinar sit amet. Etiam in lacus feugiat, imperdiet nunc et, consectetur dui. Quisque tempor nisl dui, ac vulputate erat dictum sit amet. Quisque et orci ut eros imperdiet commodo et eget diam. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse volutpat, ligula id eleifend dignissim, leo urna iaculis massa, eu eleifend nisi urna ut tortor. Vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="reptiles" class="content">
      <h1>Reptiles</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis pellentesque libero. Praesent hendrerit justo hendrerit lacus rutrum, sit amet cursus arcu molestie. Duis libero ipsum, blandit at nisl vitae, convallis lobortis nulla. In pulvinar tempor justo, ut lacinia ligula vestibulum quis. Quisque elementum urna nisl, eget laoreet dolor pulvinar sit amet. Etiam in lacus feugiat, imperdiet nunc et, consectetur dui. Quisque tempor nisl dui, ac vulputate erat dictum sit amet. Quisque et orci ut eros imperdiet commodo et eget diam. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse volutpat, ligula id eleifend dignissim, leo urna iaculis massa, eu eleifend nisi urna ut tortor. Vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="amphibians" class="content">
      <h1>Amphibians</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis pellentesque libero. Praesent hendrerit justo hendrerit lacus rutrum, sit amet cursus arcu molestie. Duis libero ipsum, blandit at nisl vitae, convallis lobortis nulla. In pulvinar tempor justo, ut lacinia ligula vestibulum quis. Quisque elementum urna nisl, eget laoreet dolor pulvinar sit amet. Etiam in lacus feugiat, imperdiet nunc et, consectetur dui. Quisque tempor nisl dui, ac vulputate erat dictum sit amet. Quisque et orci ut eros imperdiet commodo et eget diam. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse volutpat, ligula id eleifend dignissim, leo urna iaculis massa, eu eleifend nisi urna ut tortor. Vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```